# Invalid characters in JSON

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pypi, azure-databricks

I have JSON with an array of struct type in string format. I am getting the following error when I was trying to write the same in a json file. I used this output file for my schema validation and causing fail because of special characters.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import * 
import pandas as pd

jsondata1 = '{"activity":[{"activity":"test","activityValue":"1"},{"activity":"test","activityValue":"1"}]}'
my_automatic_schema = json_schema.dumps(jsondata1)
my_automatic_schema

atoDF = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize([my_automatic_schema]))
atoDF.write.format("json").save("mnt//Users/name/test3.json")
```

I am  expecting the following output:
`'{"activity": [{"activityValue": "str", "activity": "str"}, "..."]}'`

and getting the below output in my JSON
`{"activity":["{\"activityValue\":\"str\",\"activity\":\"str\"}","..."]}`

Please help me provide a solution about how to get rid of special characters in my output file

Comment: not following ... your json is a string or a bunch of json files?

Answer (score 0):

Try using raw string like this:

```
jsondata1 = r'{"activity":[{"activity":"test","activityValue":"1"},{"activity":"test","activityValue":"1"}]}'
```